# Using higher topos theory to study Cech cohomology

Tags: higher-category-theory, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, infinity-topos-theory, cech-cohomology

It seems to me that many classical statements about Cech cohomology should without much effort follow from Lurie's HTT, but I am struggling to fill out the details. I want to show that, given an ordinary sheaf $A \in \operatorname{Sh}(X, \operatorname{Ch}(\mathbb{Z}))$ of chain complexes on a topological space $X$,

- The functor that sends an open subset $U$ to the derived sections $\operatorname{R \Gamma}(U,A) \in D(\mathbb{Z})$ in the derived $\infty$-category is an $\infty$-sheaf.
- If $A = F[n]$ is concentrated in degree $n >0$, for $F$ an ordinary sheaf of abelian groups, then (under the Dold-Kan correspondence) $A$ corresponds to the Eilenberg-Maclane object $B^n F$ defined in HTT, as suggested in [this n-lab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/abelian+sheaf+cohomology).

From the first statement (if it is true), one can show Theorem 3.8 on the correspondence between Cech and sheaf cohomology in the [n-lab article on Cech cohomology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%C4%8Cech+cohomology#relation_to_abelian_sheaf_cohomology), by using the fact that the Cech complex calculates the homotopy limit that describes descent for $\infty$-sheaves. I also want to prove Theorem 3.7:

- On a paracompact Hausdorff space $X$, Cech cohomology and sheaf cohomology agree:
  $$ \operatorname{\check{H}}^*(X,A) \cong \operatorname{H}^*(X,A) $$
  Here, the Cech complex is defined by taking the colimit over all covers of $X$.

The mentioned nlab articles of course give references on the classical proofs of these statements (as well as, in the first case, a proof via simplicial cosheaves); but I am interested in whether, and how, one can abstractly deduce them from results in Lurie's books. In particular, Chapter 7 in HTT develops a lot of theory for paracompact Hausdorff spaces, and this would be an interesting application. I would be very greatful for some hints or references on how this works.

Comment: The first statement is basically a tautology, depending on your definitions. The point is that every covering sieve becomes a colimit diagram in the topos, so taking sections yields a sheaf.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for your comment! I am a bit confused, wouldn't taking sections of $A$ require that we first show that $A$ is an object of the topos? In other words, if we let $L: \operatorname{Ch}(\mathbb{Z}) \to D( \mathbb{Z} )$ be the localization functor into the derived $\infty$-category, we would have to show that $L \circ A$ is a sheaf. This does not seem clear, as $L$ doesn't preserve limits - but maybe I use the wrong definitions/ point of view, as you say.

Comment: Ah. Actually, I think that definition probably does not work at all. You need to think of $A$ as an object in the derived category of chain complexes of sheaves.

Comment: You are right, what I propose in my last comment is definitely wrong, as it is not enough to replace $A$ by an injective on each open, but has to replace the whole sheaf. But I still think $R \Gamma ( - , A)$ should be an $\infty$-sheaf in $D(\mathbb{Z})$, since this is essentially what the correspondence between Cech and sheaf cohomology in nlab 3.7 says. As long as we work over $\mathbb{Z}$, we can apply the Dold-Kan correspondence as in the first link and the statement should become, as you say, tautological; but for any ring I still think one should work in $D(R)$-valued $\infty$-sheaves?

Comment: The point is that you have to give an ($\infty$-categorical) definition of $R\Gamma$. There are some tricky point such as hypercompleteness.

Comment: I don't know any Dold–Kan correspondence for unbounded chain complexes.

Comment: @MarkusZetto So you are asking for a proof that the derived category of chain complexes of sheaves is equivalent to the category of sheaves of objects in the derived category of chain complexes (inserting $\infty$ appropriately)? That is actually a non-trivial fact, but the direction you are interested in is the easy one.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I got a bit sick the last days. @ZhenLin Yes, it seems like this is what I am looking for - SAG 2.1.2.2 seems to go in that direction, is it a good idea to follow the proof there or should I look for a more specific reference?

Comment: @Z.M Your comment also seems to be related to that (and you are of course right, Dold-Kan only works like this in the bounded case), isn't it? Making an object of the derived category of chain complexes of sheaves into a sheaf in the derived category seems to rely on this construction.

Comment: No, I do not have a reference. But I'm sure someone does and will give you one if you ask a separate question specifically about it. At the most basic level this is a question about strictification: if we forget about coverages for a moment this reduces to showing that the homotopy $(\infty, 1)$-category of the category of presheaves valued in a model category $\mathcal{M}$ is equivalent to the $(\infty, 1)$-category of presheaves valued in the homotopy $(\infty, 1)$-category of $\mathcal{M}$.